# Can't connect to a SQL Server named instance

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I run several applications that require SQL Server. I usually use SQL Server Express. After the latest Windows 10 update, my profile became corrupted, so reinstalled windows. I had been wanting to play around with SSRS, so I installed SQL Server 2016 Dev edition. After installing, I tried to connect from SSMS  using `hostname\instance` and Windows authentication and I got error 87

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)

I tried removing the instance name and just connecting using the hostname, and the connection succeeded. With SQL Server Express I always needed the instance name. Why is it no longer necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect without specifying an instance name, the client connects to whichever instance is listening on port 1433. This is typically the default instance. A named instance usually listens on a different port so either the instance name or port number must be specified in the connection string.

Unless you specify otherwise, SQL Server Developer Edition will install as the default instance (if no default instance already exists). In contrast, Express installs as a named instance (name SQLEXPRESS unless you change it) but you can explicitly install as the default instance if desired.

Comment: it just seems to strange to me that the connection fails when i use the instance name but it succeeds without the instance name.

Comment: @user2378895, the default instance has no name (not to be confused with the instance id). If the Windows service name is :"SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)", it is the default instance and no name should be specified when connecting.